# Using IF logic within a HTML form to direct to different URLs

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new to JavaScript and trying to create a form that will take the user to a sub-domain based their input. User enters a string, selects a value from a drowdown menu. Once user clicks submit, they will be taken to a custom URL based on their input.

For some reason my IF statement doesn't work and prefix is always equals to `a1`.

Here is the code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function goToPage() {

  var prefix;

  if (document.getElementById('model').value = 93) {
    prefix = "a1";
  }

  else if (document.getElementById('model').value = 95) {
    prefix = "a2";
  }

  else {
    prefix = "a3";
  }

  window.location = "https://example.com/" + prefix + "/" + document.getElementById('string').value;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="string" />
<select id="model" />
  <option value="93" />9-3</option>
  <option value="95" />9-5</option>
<option value="96" />9-6</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="goToPage();" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using assignment operator (`=`) in the condition, that's why the condition always evaluates to `true`. You have to use the comparison operator (`==` or `===`).

**Please Note:** Since the input values are of type string and you are comparing that with number, it is better to convert them to number before the comparison. Also the HTML tags (*select* and *option*) you are using closes them in the start tag itself (as if they are self-closing) which is not valid HTML syntax.

Try the following way:

```js
function goToPage() {
  var elValue = Number(document.getElementById('model').value);
  var prefix;
  if (elValue == 93) {
    prefix = "a1";
  }
  else if (elValue == 95) {
    prefix = "a2";
  }
  else {
    prefix = "a3";
  }

  window.location = "https://example.com/" + prefix + "/" + document.getElementById('string').value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="string" />
<select id="model">
  <option value="93">9-3</option>
  <option value="95">9-5</option>
  <option value="96">9-6</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="goToPage();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use assignment operators. Single equation marks means assignment operator.  Use double equal marks in conditions.

```
if (document.getElementById('model').value == 93)
```